# How to detect the disappearing of the on-screen keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

Since the on-screen keyboard takes a lot of space on mobile devices, I would like to change the layout of a page of my website when the user selects a field to enter some information, and cancel these changes when the user leaves the field. Basically I want to hide some elements to save some space. I've tried to use the JavaScript "focusout" and "blur" events, but they don't work properly: a user might click on an area of the page, which would make the on-screen keyboard disappear, but the cursor would remain in the field and the "focusout"/"blur" event wouldn't be triggered. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I've only seen this observationally, so I'm not 100% sure if it would work. However, the Window Height appears to change when the keyboard is open, perhaps you could look for a change in this? - Bear in mind, this would also happen when orientation changes.

Comment: @Lewis Thanks for the suggestion. As you mentioned, this solution isn't the best in my case.